# Commutative diagram using Tikzcd in footnote

Tags: footnotes, tikz-arrows, tikz-cd

I want a commutative diagram in a footnote using tikzcd. For footnotes I just use the standard \footnote command. However, using `\[\begin{tikzcd}A&B\\C&D\end{tikzcd}\]` inside the footnote gives just [image] instead of all four letters. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Could you please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) to your question? Also, do you get any error messages from your code?

Comment: Thank you! Will include a minimal working example next time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Welcome to TeX-SE! You need to use an ampersand replacement (or another trick), but then it works.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\[\begin{tikzcd}A&B\\C&D\end{tikzcd}\] 

X\footnote{\[\begin{tikzcd}[ampersand replacement=\&]A\&B\\C\&D\end{tikzcd}\]}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I think that your solution is unique: see the manual pag. 13 *By default, TikZ makes the character & active inside matrices, and this causes the error message
! Package pgfbasematrix Error: Single ampersand used with wrong catcode.
when {tikzcd} is used inside the argument to a macro such as a Beamer frame or a footnote.*

Comment: @Sebastiano Thanks! I think you could also use a savebox. But yes, I think this is the most direct solution.

Comment: Perfect! I do not really understand why this works, but it helps. Thank you!

Comment: @EBP And ampersand is a special character, which can cause all sorts of little headaches here and there. And `\footnote` and `\section` commands, beamer frames and so on are special, so there some "standard tricks" one can use. By now this site has as a huge repertoire of these tricks, very often a google search with `site:tex.stackexchange.com` and the error message will drag you to a trick (but this one I knew out of the top of my hat because I have seen similar questions before).

Answer (score 0):

This solution uses a savebox.  Interestingly, the `\savebox` macro didn't work, even though it should be equivalent.

Note that `\box` automatically empties the contents, while `\usebox` preserves them.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\newsavebox{\tempbox}
\begin{document}
\[\begin{tikzcd}A&B\\C&D\end{tikzcd}\] 

\setbox\tempbox=\hbox{\begin{tikzcd}A&B\\C&D\end{tikzcd}}%
X\footnote{\[\box\tempbox\]}
\end{document}
```